# Error when django import rpy2 but OK with single python file (NotImplementedError)

Tags: python, r, django, rpy2, r-package

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector

packageNames = ('afex', 'emmeans')
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)

packnames_to_install = [x for x in packageNames if not rpackages.isinstalled(x)]

# Running R in Python example installing packages:
if len(packnames_to_install) > 0:
   utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames_to_install))

data = robjects.r('read.table(file ="R.appendix3.data", header = T)')
data.head()
afex = rpackages.importr('afex')
model = afex.aov_ez('Subject', 'Recall', data, within='Valence')
emmeans = rpackages.importr('emmeans', robject_translations={"recover.data.call": "recover_data_call1"})
pairwise = emmeans.emmeans(model, "Valence", contr="pairwise", adjust="holm")
print(pairwise)
```

The python file imports rpy2 to use the function of r package. It's OK, but an error is occured in the Django framework (same code).

```
NotImplementedError at /myapp/test/
Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type '<class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpClosure'>'
```

What can I do to prevent it from happening? I want to implement the r package on the web under django.Thanks so much.

Comment: I'd be happy to look into it, but you need to post a self-contained example. I'm missing the data file it seems

Comment: Thank you, Kesh. I backversioned rpy2 from 3.5.5 to 3.5.1 and the error is gone. I want to know is it convenient to use R package function in django development by rpy2?@kesh

Comment: glad to hear it was an easy fix. I'm not familiar with django, so can't comment much on how rpy2 works with it.